# How to Implement Lazy Loading of Multiple Datasources in Quarkus?

Tags: postgresql, quarkus, flyway

I am working on a project where I have multiple datasources with distinct users and databases (DBA, MIG, and APP) in a Quarkus and Flyway environment. Each user has a specific role:

**DBA:** Connects to the PostgreSQL database, creates the database and all users. The migration is done programmatically using Flyway.
**MIG:** Creates tables and other database objects required by the APP datasource for operational purposes. This is also migrated using Flyway, but within the database instance created by the DBA user.
**APP:** Executes queries and inserts against the database objects created by the MIG Datasource.

Since I have the DBA user creating the database and users, APP user's table is not found.

The issue I am facing is that when I define the datasource property for the MIG/APP user, it does not find the database because the DBA Flyway migration has not yet been executed. I have been looking for a way to implement lazy loading of datasources in Quarkus, but so far, I have not found a solution.

I understand that I could have an init script for the docker postgres container, but I would like to use flyway for the database creation too (I know it is not recommended, however I would prefer the migration with flyway).

I would appreciate any suggestions or innovative solutions to this problem. Thank you!